# A Surjective Function from $[0,1] \setminus \{0.5\}$ to $[0,1]$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm taking Discrete Mathematics this semester and I got this question in one of my homework tasks. I've tried thinking about the solution over and over but can't seem to come up with anything. The question goes like this:

Is there a surjective function from $[0,1] \setminus \{0.5\}$ to $[0,1]$ such that $f(a)>f(b)$ implies $a>b$?

I must mention that sadly I cannot use any arguments involving cardinality.

Comment: Hint: Intuitively you might come to the conclusion that such a function $f$ has to "miss" at least one value in $[0,1]$. How would you characterize this value in terms of $f$?

Comment: Assume such a function exists. Surjectivity implies that at least one argument maps onto $\frac{1}{2}$. What can you say about that argument?

Comment: The correct statement of the exercise is: **"...such that $a<b$ implies $f(a)<f(b)$"**. Please check your notes.

Comment: @R.G. Not much... :-)

Comment: @Did Hey! Sorry for my English :) it's written like this: 
F(a)>F(b) -> a>b

Comment: OK, then you copied correctly the exercise (and it is slightly idiotic). If ever this was given to you by a living human, I suggest to ask them whether the implication should not go the other way or if the two $>$ should not be $\ge$...

Comment: @Did But it does make some sense considering the example below?

Comment: The example below answers the exercise as it is stated at the moment. The statement of the exercise as it is stated at the moment is probably incorrect. Is this what you are asking me?

Comment: @Did I'd like to know why it's incorrect :) (the statement as it is)

Comment: I did not say the answer below was incorrect. I suggested that the statement in your question at the present time is probably not the statement you were asked to prove and I based this guess on the fact that a classical and much more interesting exercise is to prove that, if $x$ is in $(0,1)$ then there exists no surjective strictly increasing function from $[0,1]\setminus\{x\}$ to $[0,1]$. But I am not your TA and in the end, they are the ones to ask about this.

Comment: @Did it sounds like a good exercise. I'll try to solve it after I'm done with the current homework, Thank you!!

Comment: Did you check the $>$ vs $\ge$ signs? Maybe you do not realize this but using one or the other changes everything...

Answer (score 1):

How about you map all values $x \in [0,0.1]$ to $10x$, and all others to 1?

Comment: Smart!! Thanks, didn't think about it this way